# Read me file with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am programming my Inno Setup Compiler that I was asking about earlier but had encountered a problem . How do I let the Installer add a Read me File?? I am using Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.3 and uses the following command "AppReadmeFile=C:\Users\Cordre\Desktop\D_C Databasis Tools\Read me.txt" in Inno but if I install the program their is no Read Me file in the Program files.
The text document does exist and is called correctly double checked that.
Is their any other command that I also have to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appreadmefile) on AppReadmeFile:

> This string, which may be a URL, is displayed on the "Support" dialog
>   of the Add/Remove Programs Control Panel applet in Windows 2000/XP and
>   later. The value may include constants.

This directive has nothing to do with a README file in the Program Files directory.  If you want a copy of the README in the Program Files directory, you'd need to add it to the `[Files]` section.  For example:

```
[Files]
Source: "MyReadme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

You can also add an icon to the file using the `[Icons]` section.  According to the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection), a sample Icons entry would be:

```
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MYPROG.EXE"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

Comment: hey . Wil jou please give me a example if I want to add the Read Me file as a icon the start up menu also please?? you said it is possible..